# Datatable.WriteXml - How to preserve spaces in element names

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I've added functionality in my application where a `DataTable` is converted into `XML`, like so:

```
dtResults.WriteXml(fileName);
```

`_x0020_` is being added instead of spaces within the outputted XML document.

Is it possible to generate XML files without the `_x0020_` code? i.e. can an XML file be generated using that method or similar, and actually have the spaces preserved?

**This is the DataGrid:**

[image]

**This is the resulting XML:**

```
<Customers>
    <Customer_x0020_Name>Sean</Customer_x0020_Name>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <Customer_x0020_Name>John</Customer_x0020_Name>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <Customer_x0020_Name>Sarah</Customer_x0020_Name>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <Customer_x0020_Name>Mark</Customer_x0020_Name>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <Customer_x0020_Name>Norman</Customer_x0020_Name>
  </Customers>
```

Comment: 20 is the hexidecimal value for a space.  Please be more specific by what you mean.

Comment: I want spaces to be generated in the XML file instead of the hex code for spaces. Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML that is being output?  Where are you seeing the hex numbers?

Comment: The XML tag names can't have spaces, so it is doing the best it can. Could you change the name of the column to "CustomerName" but display "Customer Name" in the column header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of your column contains a space.  XML element names cannot contain a space.  A space is used in XML to separate element names from attribute names, for instance:

```
<ElementName Attribute1="value" />
```

The `DataTable.WriteXml` method tries to write out the XML file in a consistent way so that another `DataTable` object can later be used to load the XML and get as close to an exact copy of the original as possible.  Therefore, it replaces illegal characters with their hex-values so that the illegal characters are not lost in translation.

So, if you want to write it to XML differently, you need to either:

- Change the name of the column in the `DataTable` so that it does not contain a space
- Manually output the XML yourself using `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, `XmlWriter`, or `XmlSerializer` and format the output however you desire
- Output the XML as you do now, but then run an XSLT script on it to fix the formatting

Comment: +1 :) Came across this today with an xml element that began with a number (also invalid as per the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name). Elements like <1_xyz> were getting the hex representation of the number 1 (<_x0031__xyz>) and <11_xyz> would get <_x0031__1_xyz>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're wanting is possible.  I don't believe an XML element name can contain a space, just like a variable name cannot contain a space.  What is the reason that it needs to be a space?

If there actually needs to be a space (which I think will render the xml useless for parsing), you can simply do a find and replace in the file.

If you're storing it to read back in and display again in a DataTable, I would just rename the columns once I've read the data back in, replacing `_x0020_` with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem. I am exporting data from an excel file which contains columns with space. So my columns also contains space. 
So I tried the following manner.

```
StringWriter strXML = new StringWriter();
dtPartOriginalData.WriteXml(strXML, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema, false);
strMessages = strXML.ToString().Replace("_x0020_", "");
```

This will replace the `_x0020_` and generates xml. But you cannot construct the same datatable using this xml. Its a workaround, I thought of adding its as a suggestion. Thank you.