# Why is The XML Serializer appending characters to my XmlAttribute?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Here is my property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The Business Unit
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("ows_Business_x0020_Unit")]
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
```

When I call Serialize on the object that has BusinessUnit I get:

```
 ows_Business_x005F_x0020_Unit=\"Hi\"
```

Where does the _x005F come from?

Comment: It's encoding the underscore. Why it's not doing it to others I don't know.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944456/how-to-preserve-spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an escape sequence. The _x0020 is actually another escape sequence for a space, so it's trying to escape the escape sequence so it doesn't get confused that you literally want the escape sequence, not the unescape value. So your attribute should look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     [XmlAttribute("ows_Business Unit")]
     public string BusinessUnit { get; set; } 
}
```

That will serialize the attribute as `ows_Business_x0020_Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft encodes certain characters as _xZZZ_, so any names that look like _xZZZ_ get escaped. They chose to handle this by searching for "_x" and encoding the underscore as _x005F.

Your life will be easier if you avoid including "_x" in any of your names.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm calling an external webservice so that isn't an option. Thanks for the explanation though :-)